# unable to get ADT plugin for Eclipse Helios: Conflicting Dependencies

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin, adt

I have Eclipse Helios 3.6 and it was working fine for my Java based web-apps.
But now i thought of developing android app for the same I finished downloading Android SDK and was on the verge of installing the ADT in Eclipse for Windows 7 from this site-> 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse but it didn't worked.

After putting above address in Install a new software under eclipse it shows both Developer tools and NDK plugins and then on clicking NEXT it is showing :

```
Android DDMS    21.0.1.v201212060256-543035
Android Development Tools   21.0.1.v201212060256-543035
Android Hierarchy Viewer    21.0.1.v201212060256-543035
Android Native Development Tools    21.0.1.v201212060256-543035
Android Traceview   21.0.1.v201212060256-543035
Tracer for OpenGL ES    21.0.1.v201212060256-543035
```

all selected but in with error :
"Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035" 
so unable to proceed.

I tried all possible solutions like trying updating Eclipse but that too started showing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to use the latest version of eclipse [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1) and the latest version of SDK and ADT